# How can I override Resharper's GetHashCode generation routine

Tags: resharper, resharper-2017

After selecting `Generate > Equality members` ReSharper generates a `GetHashCode()` method with body

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        var hashCode = (int) Property1;
        hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Property2;
        hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Property3.GetHashCode();
...
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

according to several articles
[What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode/#263416)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function#FNV-1a_hash

I'd like to generate my own `GetHashCode()` method
(inspired by first SO answer)

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = (int) 2166136261;
        hash = (hash * 16777619) ^ Property1.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 16777619) ^ Property2.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 16777619) ^ Property3.GetHashCode();
...
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Is it possible ? How ?